# Have Both And/Where In PHP SQL Statement

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0

I connect to MSSQL server and my query does not return any results - if I use the `echo $sql;` statement all that I have returned is `Array` so I can't even check for a syntax issue!

How should this syntax be ammended so that all 3 where statements execute as they should?

```
    <select name="employee" id="employee"></select>
$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql';
$option['host'] = 'IP ADDRESS';
$option['user'] = 'USER';
$option['password'] = 'Pass';
$option['database'] = 'DB';
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quotename(array('Red,Blue,Green')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('EMS'));
$datefield_name = $db->quoteName('TermDate');
$employee_name = $db->quoteName('employee');
$query->where("$datefield_name >= " . $db->quote($d1), 'AND');
$query->where("$datefield_name <= " . $db->quote($d2));
if ($employeename != 'All') {
    $query->where("$employee_name <= " . $db->quote($employee));
}
$db->setQuery($query);
echo $query;
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: You're clearly using some type of built database class. Without knowing that you're using the structure of the class properly, we can't help you. We need that database class in order to help. Also, I do not see a variable named $sql. If you mean $query, then use var_export($query) to figure out what it says. But $query is an instance of $db and then you pass it back to the database instance. We need your database class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at MSSQL, but my first impression is that in your where-statements you should not include your variables inside the quotes. So instead of

```
$query->where("$datefield_name <= " . $db->quote($d2));
```

try

```
$query->where($datefield_name . " <= " . $db->quote($d2));
```

Comment: It may not be "proper" syntax, but I run it on a few other Joomla articles and it works as expected.